# problems with user defined function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a trouble when running my R code. It contains a few functions, but the problem happens when the following function is called:

```
w <- function(p) {

   if (p == 1) pr <- 1
   if (p == 0) pr <- 0
   if (p != 0 && p != 1) pr <- exp(-(-log(p))^sigma)

   return(pr)
}
```

The problem occurs when the argument of this w function becomes 1. I checked it with step by step execution. I found that when I have w(c1) in the other function and c1 has the value of 1, than the return of my w function is NaN. I am really confused because when I simply write w(1), I get 1, but when I have w(c1), where c1 was computed to be 1 in the other function, then w function does not work. In step by step execution, when c1 becomes 1, the first if condition suddenly does not work, it returns FALSE, but it should be the opposite, since c1 does equal 1.

What can be the solution to this problem?

Comment: I guess that `c1` is not exactly 1 but is a little more than 1. Try `print(c1,digits=22)` to see its "exact" value. Remember that R is just showing the first few digits of a number; see for instance: `x<-1.0000000001;x` and `x==1`.

Comment: your words are confusing me. a concrete example would help. maybe your calculated 1 is not exactly 1 which means that `p == 1` will not be true (you should use `all.equal` here instead anyway) and a negative number raised to a power of 1.xxx will be NaN

Comment: Depends on the value of `sigma`, which is absent in your question.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answers! Actually the problem was with c1. It turned out that c1 in my case equals: 1.000000000000000222045.

Comment: The recommended fix is to use `all.equal` for comparison---it allows for small differences based on your machine precision. So instead of `p == 1`, use `all.equal(p, 1)`.

Comment: A handy (sez the author) alternative to `all.equal` is the function `approxeq` in the `cgwtools` package available at https://github.com/cellocgw/cgwtools_rev2 .  The difference is that `all.equal` checks object attributes as well as numeric value, and often returns non-logical responses.

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)